# Calling free() on malloc()'d char pointer causes program to crash with invalid pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I was learning C and playing a bit with heap memory when I encountered this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char* test = malloc(1024);
    test = "Hello!";
    printf("%s\n", test);
    free(test);
    return 0;
}
```

What I think it should do:

- Allocate 1024 bytes on the heap
- Write "Hello!\0" to the start of that memory
- Write to `stdout` from the start of the pointer I got from `malloc()` till it finds a `\0`
- Free the 1024 bytes of memory allocated with `malloc()`
- Return 0

But, my program just crashes when `free()` is called. Why?

```
~$ ./mem                                                                                                                                                              
Hello!
*** Error in `./mem': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400684 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7f9f99ac5725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x1a8)[0x7f9f99ad1c18]
./mem[0x4005ec]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f9f99a6e830]
./mem[0x4004e9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3801151                            /home/gala/mem
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 3801151                            /home/gala/mem
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 3801151                            /home/gala/mem
015e6000-01607000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f9f99838000-7f9f9984e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1970703                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9f9984e000-7f9f99a4d000 ---p 00016000 08:01 1970703                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9f99a4d000-7f9f99a4e000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 1970703                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9f99a4e000-7f9f99c0e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1970665                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9f99c0e000-7f9f99e0d000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 1970665                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9f99e0d000-7f9f99e11000 r--p 001bf000 08:01 1970665                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9f99e11000-7f9f99e13000 rw-p 001c3000 08:01 1970665                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9f99e13000-7f9f99e17000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9f99e17000-7f9f99e3d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1970637                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9f9a013000-7f9f9a016000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9f9a039000-7f9f9a03c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9f9a03c000-7f9f9a03d000 r--p 00025000 08:01 1970637                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9f9a03d000-7f9f9a03e000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 1970637                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9f9a03e000-7f9f9a03f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffcc81cb000-7ffcc81ec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffcc81f8000-7ffcc81fa000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffcc81fa000-7ffcc81fc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
[1]    12941 abort      ./mem
```

Comment: `test = "Hello!";` is wrong, it does not write to allocated memory, but throws away your pointer and overwrites it by pointer to string `"Hello!"`

Comment: char* test = strdup("Hello");

Comment: @jpw - `strncpy` would be slightly better

Comment: @EdHeal: [No, `strncpy` would not be better than `strcpy`](https://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: In addition to the information given in the comments and answers, you should confirm that `malloc` succeeded before copying data to the allocated memory. `malloc` returns `NULL` on failure.

Comment: `sprintf` also looks a good option . It would also append nul terminator.

Comment: @KeithThompson - i said *slightly* better

Comment: @EdHeal: I know. `strcnpy` is **worse**. Follow the link in my previous comment for details (it's an article on my blog).

Comment: @KeithThompson - I disagree - These things need you be use on advisement. What is the alternative; I would imagine that one knows the length of the array that you are copying into but not sure of the array you are copying from (as the array you are copying to is closer to your chest). `strncpy` will not copy too much. Bung in the extra null character afterwards and we are safe.  I am interested to know what is your alternative

Comment: @EdHeal: In this case, my alternative is `strcpy` *if* you can safely assume that the target array is long enough (which is certainly the case here). Otherwise, I might use `strcat` after setting `target[0` to `'\0'`. `snprintf` is another option, though it might be overkill. `strncpy` isn't really a string function. It's meant to deal with a very specialized data structure that isn't often used.

Comment: But `strcat` may lead to buffer overrun?

Comment: @KeithThompson - Is is usually the case that the length of target is know but the length of the source is the problem?

Comment: @EdHeal: The length of the source had better be known; otherwise you can't safely copy anything into it. Sure, `strcat` can cause a buffer overrun. There are a number of ways to avoid that. `strncat` is just a particularly bad and error-prone solution. Incidentally, most of these solutions ignore the question of what you should do if the target isn't big enough. Quietly truncating the data is rarely the right thing to do. (Error handling is hard.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in the comments, this is what going on:

```
int main(void) {
    char* test = malloc(1024);     /* You allocate, great! */
    test = "Hello!";               /* Huh, what's this? You point 'test' 
                                    * to some area in the code section.
                                    * Valid, but considering you just 
                                    * allocated some memory, strange */
    printf("%s\n", test);          /* Print out a string from the code
                                    * section: fine. */
    free(test);                    /* What?! You want to try to free() the
                                    * memory in the code section? That's a 
                                    * big no-no! */
    return 0;                      /* whatever */
}
```

Now, what you should do:

```
int main(void) {
    char* test = malloc(1024);     /* You allocate, great! */
    strcpy(test, "Hello!");        /* Copy some data into that 
                                    * allocated memory */
    printf("%s\n", test);          /* Print out a string from the
                                    * heap: fine. */
    free(test);                    /* Free that allocated memory! */
    return 0;                      /* aaaand, we're done */
}
```

Comment: You want 7, not 6.

Comment: You would have to take care of nul terminator after `strncpy`, just for safety.

Comment: Nice! Where is the string "Hello!" passed to strncpy() being stored? The stack as a local variable? Is it discarded right after the call?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: `strncpy(test, "Hello!", 6);` is unsafe. It copies just the 6 characters into the allocated memory, leaving garbage in the remainder. There's no guarantee that you'll have a null-terminated string, so the `printf` has undefined behavior. [`strncpy()` is not a safer `strcpy()`](https://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: @amalloy: No, you want `strcpy`, not `strncpy`. Using `strncpy` *might* make sense if you give it the size of the target rather than the size of the source.

Comment: @Gala the literal `"Hello!"` is in the code section. `strcpy` copies it byte-for-byte into the memory location on the heap you just allocated. The literal string is still there and will be the entirety of the lifetime of the program.

Comment: That is strange. Is there any advantage then to allocate things to the heap like this? I've just started C on Linux, and I have yet to find a good usage for the heap space.

Comment: @Gala: Heap allocation is for when you don't know until run time either how much memory you'll need, or how many allocations you'll need, or both.

Comment: @Gala, the heap is not very useful for static strings that never change, but it is useful for data that does change, or for large pieces of data (otherwise stack might overflow and other nasty stuff)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So its good for loading huge amounts of unpredictably long crap like HTML or XML, or even JSON? Great!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the complex world of C!

Basically, you're overwriting your pointer `test` with an address of `"Hello!"` (which is static immutable array).

And it crashes because you try to free a thing that you have not created.

You should use `strcpy()` or a loop to copy your string into `text`.

Comment: For historical reasons, C string literals are not `const`. `"Hello!"` is of type `char[7]`, not `const char[7]`. But attempting to modify a string literal has undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, I've not expected that. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

test is initially pointing to memory allocated by malloc of size 1024.
Now in the next line you are pointing test to memory referenced by "Hello!".
So your test pointer is now pointing to "Hello!" and not what you allocated in the first place using malloc.
Now you are trying to free "Hello!", which is invalid because this memory is not been allocated using malloc and hence your programming is crashing.

```
char* test = malloc(1024);
test = "Hello!"; /* This is wrong. You pointer is pointing to "Hello!" string base address */
```

To store "Hello!" in memory allocated by test, you need to use memcpy.
so instead of :

```
test = "Hello!"
```

use :

```
memcpy(test, "Hello!", sizeof("Hello!");
```

This will fix your code.

Comment: strcpy terminates when it encounters null char, memcpy will copy exact bytes specified in last parameter for you irrespective whether the source is null terminated or not. Either of them will work for you in this cases. But try to develop habit of either using "strncpy and not strcpy" or memcpy. But provided that strncpy is specific for string I would rather say to use memcpy.

Comment: In this case, `memcpy(test, "Hello!", sizeof("Hello!");` does *exactly* the same thing as `strcpy(test, "Hello!");` -- except that you have to specify the source string twice, which is error-prone. `strncpy` is dangerous when not used *very* carefully; it's not really a string function (see the article I've linked to in other comments).